# Unable to download a file from S3 by the URL in a browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, google-chrome

I have such code snippet that used to be work with the previous versions of Google Chrome, but now it does not work. When I run this script I redirected to the page with the content of the file(it's a text) and with AWS URL(the same as in setAttribute).

```
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXX/XXX/XXX?Signature=XXX&Expires=XXX&AWSAccessKeyId=XXX');
element.setAttribute('download', 'filename.txt');
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
```

How to download this file?

Comment: Maybe it's to do with settings on the browser how to behave when a download link it clicked?  Chrome "opens" a lot of file extensions by default in a previewer rather than downloading the files.

Comment: @Nope I'm not able to change settings on the user's browsers.

Comment: check if HTTP header Content-Disposition is present in the response headers and if it's set to "filename.txt".

Comment: @BorisS Yes, it's present: Content-Disposition: inline;filename=filename.txt;filename*=UTF-8''filename.txt

Comment: Here your problem lies: Content-Disposition: inline, it should be 
Content-Disposition: attachment. Browsers ( and latest verstions of Chrome) favour Content-Disposition header over download attribute

Comment: @BorisS Can I add Content-Disposition: attachment parameter to the URL?

Comment: No, you can't. I assume you have an access to S3 management console ? It's is possible to edit file's metadata. 
check this tutorial: http://iwantmyreal.name/s3-download-only-presigned-upload

Comment: [Block cross-origin <a download>](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4969697975992320)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an error in the comments. 
Chrome still favours download attribute, but it completely ignores it if the anchor element has cross origin attributes ( meaning, if the file is hosted on a different domain).

To be able to download it, file needs to be served with header: *Content-Disposition: attachment;*

Check this tutorial to see how to set Content-Disposition in s3 management console: http://iwantmyreal.name/s3-download-only-presigned-upload

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
    let downloadImage = url => {
      let urlArray = url.split("/")
      let bucket = urlArray[3]
      let key = `${urlArray[4]}/${urlArray[5]}`
      let s3 = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: bucket }})
      let params = {Bucket: bucket, Key: key}
      s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        let blob=new Blob([data.Body], {type: data.ContentType});
        let link=document.createElement('a');
        link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download=url;
        link.click();
      })
    }
```

The url parameter refers to the full url of the image.

Comment: I had to use `new Blob([new Uint8Array(data.Body.data)], {type: data.ContentType})` for this to work