# Download attribute doesn't working on chrome or edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

i'm try to use the download attribute. but it doesn't work.
i try to use also target and  try to understadnd if there is some issue trying to download from the server or from the web (https).
nothings work.

can you please check and let me know what wrong here?
chrome version 86.0.4240.198

```html
    <a href="using_new_elements_dd.txt" download ="ee"> Click here to download </a> 
    <br>
    <a href = "../kindergarten-screening_module2_1.webp" target = "_self" download> download with target</a>
    <br>
    <a href = "https://d25tv1xepz39hi.cloudfront.net/2016-08-01/files/picture-style_1311.jpg"  target = "_self"  download> download with target from https</a>
```

Comment: when clicking the link it open in a new tab and not downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Probably specifying content-disposition & content-type in metadata from s3 console should work.

Refer:

- http://iwantmyreal.name/s3-download-only-presigned-upload
- [Unable to download a file from S3 by the URL in a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151062/unable-to-download-a-file-from-s3-by-the-url-in-a-browser)